# Register-ClusteredScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task

While executing below Register-ClusteredScheduledTask i am getting this error.

> Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterTaskName -TaskType AnyNode -Xml $TaskXML | Out-Null

```
Register-ClusteredScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect.

At C:\Setup-Scheduler.ps1:215 char:5
+     Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterTaskName -TaskT ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (PS_ClusteredScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...ed
ScheduledTask) [Register-ClusteredScheduledTask], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: HRESULT 0x80070057,Register-ClusteredScheduledTask
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo />
  <Triggers>
            <TimeTrigger>
          <Repetition>
            <Interval>PT15M</Interval>
            <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
          </Repetition>
          <StartBoundary>2016-11-08T13:26:00</StartBoundary>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </TimeTrigger>
        <TimeTrigger>
          <Repetition>
            <Interval>PT5H</Interval>
            <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
          </Repetition>
          <StartBoundary>2016-11-09T19:29:00</StartBoundary>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </TimeTrigger>
        <CalendarTrigger>
          <StartBoundary>2016-11-09T19:29:00</StartBoundary>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <ScheduleByDay>
            <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
          </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
        <CalendarTrigger>
          <StartBoundary>2016-11-09T00:00:00</StartBoundary>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <ScheduleByMonth>
            <DaysOfMonth>
              <Day>9</Day>
            </DaysOfMonth>
            <Months>
              <January />
              <February />
              <March />
              <April />
              <May />
              <June />
              <July />
              <August />
              <September />
              <October />
              <November />
              <December />
            </Months>
          </ScheduleByMonth>
        </CalendarTrigger>
        <CalendarTrigger>
          <StartBoundary>2016-11-09T00:00:00</StartBoundary>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <ScheduleByMonth>
            <DaysOfMonth>
              <Day>9</Day>
            </DaysOfMonth>
            <Months>
              <November />
            </Months>
          </ScheduleByMonth>
        </CalendarTrigger>

  </Triggers>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT10M</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <Volatile>true</Volatile>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Schedulers\CrystalHR\ADMS Download Command\ADMSManualCommand.exe</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\Schedulers\CrystalHR\ADMS Download Command</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

To verify where my XML is correct i used the same xml with below code

> Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Dummy" -Xml $TaskXML -User "XX\YY" -Password "XXXXX" -Force | Out-Null

and it worked correctly. Then my XML should be correct.

I also tried registering the clustered scheduler task by directly using simple Trigger and Action and even that worked.

> Register-ClusteredScheduledTask -TaskName $ClusterTaskName -TaskType AnyNode -Trigger $SingleTaskTrigger -Action $TaskAction | Out-Null

It looks like the my xml which works with standard scheduled task does not work with clustered scheduler task due to some invalid parameter which not documented for clustered task anywhere. Do anyone have a such documentation for the same?

Please help me out.

**UPDATE**

After running `$Error[0] | fl -f` got below error

```
writeErrorStream      : True
OriginInfo            :
Exception             : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: The
                        parameter is incorrect.

                           at Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Internal.Oper
                        ations.CimAsyncObserverProxyBase`1.ProcessNativeCallbac
                        k(OperationCallbackProcessingContext
                        callbackProcessingContext, T currentItem, Boolean
                        moreResults, MiResult operationResult, String
                        errorMessage, InstanceHandle errorDetailsHandle)
TargetObject          : PS_ClusteredScheduledTask
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PS_ClusteredScheduledTask:Root/Micros
                        oft/...edScheduledTask)
                        [Register-ClusteredScheduledTask], CimException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Register-ClusteredScheduledTask
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      :
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1, 0}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: Do you have a corrupted scheduled task? https://powershell.org/forums/topic/register-scheduledtask/

This article writes about using set-clusteredscheduledtask rather than registering in case it is already registered. http://serverfault.com/questions/623407/powershell-set-clusteredscheduledtask-error-incorrect-function

Hope this helps. 
Thanks, Tim.

Comment: I have already looked into that. I have check with Get-ClusteredScheduledTask and found no task and the cluster is also configured correctly since i am able to create simple task without xml.

Comment: Could you please duplicate the error and then run the following code: `$Error[0] | fl -f`.  That should provide more detailed info about what's going on.  Please update your answer with the result.

Comment: From http://serverfault.com/questions/623919/powershell-register-clusteredscheduledtask-from-xml it says that -xml is expecting a string. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Thank you for updating with the additional error details.  The error is actually from the Task Scheduler and not from Powershell.  This means Powershell validated your inputs and passed them to the scheduler which returned the error.  You'll need to do additional troubleshooting to track down the cause.  This can be from security settings, service hang ups, and even patch level.

Comment: @TimHaintz I am passing the xml string only not xml file path. If i use xml path it will show "The task XML is malformed" error and i know that.

Comment: @Colyn1337, Thanks for your replies. How do i troubleshooting? How can i create clustered scheduler task from Task Scheduler to troubleshoot? Is there any other tool through which i can test?

Comment: Hi Vivek, is $ClusterTaskName a string? I usually see 'the parameter is incorrect' when parameter sets are mixed up. In this case, the XML parameter set looks fine.

Comment: @TimHaintz, Thanks for the replies, Yes it is a string. I can create a simple clustered task using the same parameter. Actually i wanted to create a monthly scheduled task which is not possible with New-ScheduledTaskTrigger so i used XML.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this issue by choosing a different task name. I have seen this under two circumstances:

1. I have a scheduled task that has become corrupt. Even deleting it won't free up the task name, it must be cached somewhere.
2. I had an unsupported character in a task name e.g. `/`

Both can be resolved by choosing a new name. I've found it useful to try creating an empty task with the name you'd like, as the errors in the GUI are better than a simple `CimException`.

Comment: I got this when I had the "/" in the name. Thanks!!

Comment: "/" in the name +1, thanks.

Comment: ":" also unsupported